# Can we use same column name multiple time in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

> I want to use same column multiple in same  query  example 6 times in
>   query how to do this to get result ?

```
            SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
            J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
            R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
            J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
            FROM  
            df_job_meta M LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON
            M.JOB_ID = J.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON 
            R.ID = J.USER_ID
            WHERE
            J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND  M.VALUE IN ('Clinical')  AND M.VALUE IN ('Full Time')   group  BY J.ID DESC
```

MY TABLE STRUCTURE IS LIKE THIS

```
  JOB_ID   |META_KEY       | VALUE
1          |  work_hour    | Full Time
1          | profile       | Clinical
1          | pay_scale     | Sharing
```

Comment: Did you tried this? If tried, you got any errors?

Comment: Use aliases, e.g. `SELECT J.ID as J_ID, R.ID as R_ID, ....`

Comment: Yes i got error. what is solution?

Comment: 1. Post the error. 2.  M.VALUE IN ('Clinical')  AND M.VALUE IN ('Full Time') IMHO return always nothing. 3. THe same field you want to place in SELECT field list? If Yes, use alias

Comment: Sorry!  error means i got  blank page . if i run this query in mysql it fetch nothing

Comment: @pratikshaarsade: You have blank page because a field can't worth Clinical and Full Time. I think you must collapse two values in IN clause

Comment: i have db structure like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have this trouble:

In your query you have add a WHERE clause like this:

```
M.VALUE IN ('Clinical') AND M.VALUE IN ('Full Time')
```

This condition is always FALSE.

You must collapse your condition in:

```
M.VALUE IN ('Clinical', 'Full Time')
```

About use of a column multiple: If you want to add in your SELECT field list the same column, you must use alias like this:

```
SELECT J.id as ID1, J.id as ID2 and so on...
```

If you want to use the same column in a WHERE condition there's no problem but pay attention to relational operator you use

**EDIT**

A further explanation about M.VALUE by an example:

Suppose you have a table named `Person`.

You have a column named `sex` where you have value F about FEMAIL and M about MALE.

So if you write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE sex = 'F' and sex = 'M'
```

you have 0 rows affected

but if you write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE sex IN ('F', 'M')
```

or equivalent

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE sex = 'F' or sex = 'M'
```

you have all rows in your table

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have one value in your use of the IN function you can replace that with equals and use or with the use of parenthesis - also group by is not ASC or DESC that is for orderby - try:

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
            J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
            R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
            J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
            FROM  
            df_job_meta M LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON
            M.JOB_ID = J.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON 
            R.ID = J.USER_ID
            WHERE
            J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND  (M.VALUE = 'Clinical'  OR M.VALUE = 'Full Time' group  BY J.ID
```

Or if you really are looking for both values then just do:

```
SELECT J.ID , J.U_POST_ID,
            J.TITLE,J.CREATION_DATE,J.STATUS,
            R.FIRST_NAME, R.LAST_NAME,R.CLINICAL_CLINIC_NAME,
            J.REQUIREMENT,J.STATE,J.CITY,J.DESCRIPTION,J.CALL_DUR,J.USER_ID
            FROM  
            df_job_meta M LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post J ON
            M.JOB_ID = J.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN df_register_users R ON 
            R.ID = J.USER_ID
            WHERE
            J.STATUS='ACTIVE'  AND R.OCCUPATION !='student' AND  M.VALUE IN ('Clinical','Full Time') group  BY J.ID
```

You can think of the Mysql IN function like PHP's in_array function.